# What happened to Xoops? still worth to use for my situation?

Tags: php, portal

I remember long time ago when I started to learn php there is a cms call xoops and it was very popular. later I went into java world and stoped paying attention on php stuffs.

but now someone gave me a 6 years old system they are currently using which is base on a very old xoops version (2.1). now almost everything I search about xoops are out date(before 2008), they did many refactors in the core code, so I can't even find proper language pack that woks with new version, and most modules only support old versions (below 2.3).

I have 2 questiones:
1- is there any cons which made people stop interest at xoops? can someone tell the the story? :D
2- the company use xoops as a portal, and they created many modules for their needs. do you recommend them keep developing new modules for xoops, o try to "migrate" (maybe remake) in other "modern" enterprise portals?

ps:I just noticed, Stackoverflow doesn't even have a tag for "xoops" this = no popular topic :O

Comment: It's tough to recommend that they stick with xoops, but there's always a little pain that comes with migration.  If they are open to a change, Drupal is pretty much the big daddy PHP CMS, with Joomla probably being second place and WordPress kind of occupying a weird space as a psuedo-general purpose CMS that grew out of blogging software, but is very popular none-the-less.  As for what happened to xoops, I have no idea, but I do recall seeing the name back in the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting older XOOPS modules is not a big problem. We're just finalizing a Basic Module Pack, with all the modules utilizing the same Admin GUI:

http://xoops.org/modules/news/article.php?storyid=6411

There is also soon a new version of XOOPS: 2.6.0, which is a major refactoring of the Core:

http://xoops.org/modules/news/article.php?storyid=6415

As with most Open Source projects, since people contribute based on their available free time, the development might be sometimes slower, sometimes faster.